# Problem with calculating the total time in MPI program using MPI_Wtime()

Tags: c, mpi, hpc

I am trying to find out the time taken by each processor and the total time taken to calculate the whole program, there seems to be some sort of error. Any suggestions and help would be much appreciated.I had used the same method for another code and it worked there, but can't seem to figure out the problem in this one.
The code I have written

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include "mpi.h"

int main(int argc, char** argv){
    int my_rank;
    double time1, time2, duration, global;
    int size;
    float a ;
    float b ;
    int n ;
    float h;
    float local_a;
    float local_b;
    int local_n;
    float integral;
    float total;
    int source;
    int dest = 0;
    int tag = 0;
    MPI_Status status;

    float Trap(float local_a, float local_b, int local_n, float h);

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &my_rank);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);
    if (my_rank == 0){
        printf("Enter a, b and n \n");
        scanf("%f %f %d", &a, &b, &n);
        for ( dest = 1 ; dest < size; dest++){
            MPI_Send(&a, 1 , MPI_FLOAT, dest , tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&b, 1 , MPI_FLOAT, dest , tag=1, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&n, 1 , MPI_INT, dest , tag=2, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }


    }
    else{
        MPI_Recv(&a, 1, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag=0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&b, 1, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag=1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
        MPI_Recv(&n, 1, MPI_INT, source, tag=2, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
    }
    MPI_Barrier(MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    time1 = MPI_Wtime();
    h = (b-a)/n;
    
    local_n = n/size;

    local_a = a + my_rank * local_n * h;

    local_b = (local_a + local_n) * h;

    integral = Trap(local_a, local_b, local_n, h);

    if (my_rank == 0){
        total = integral;
        for (source = 1; source < size; source++){
            MPI_Recv(&integral, 1, MPI_FLOAT, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &status);
            total += integral;
        }
    }
    else {
        MPI_Send(&integral, 1, MPI_FLOAT, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD); 
    }
    time2 = MPI_Wtime();
    duration = time2 - time1;
    MPI_Reduce(&duration, &global,1,MPI_DOUBLE,MPI_SUM,0,MPI_COMM_WORLD);      

    if (my_rank == 0){
        printf("With n = %d trapezoids, our estimate \n", n);
        printf("of the integral from %f to %f = %0.8f\n",a,b,total);
        printf("Global runtime is %f\n",global);
    }    
    printf("Runtime at %d is %f \n", my_rank,duration); 
    MPI_Finalize();
 
}

float Trap(float local_a, float local_b, int local_n, float h){
    float integral;
    float x;
    int i;

    float f(float x);
    integral = (f(local_a) + f(local_b))/2.0;
    x = local_a;
    for (int i = 1; i <= local_n-1; i++){
        x += h;
        integral += f(x);
    }
    integral *= h;

}

float f(float x){
    return x*x;
}
```

The error that it shows

```
[Sid-Laptop:4987] *** An error occurred in MPI_Recv
[Sid-Laptop:4987] *** reported by process [852688897,2]
[Sid-Laptop:4987] *** on communicator MPI_COMM_WORLD
[Sid-Laptop:4987] *** MPI_ERR_RANK: invalid rank
[Sid-Laptop:4987] *** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
[Sid-Laptop:4987] ***    and potentially your MPI job)
Enter a, b and n 
[Sid-Laptop:04980] 2 more processes have sent help message help-mpi-errors.txt / mpi_errors_are_fatal
[Sid-Laptop:04980] Set MCA parameter "orte_base_help_aggregate" to 0 to see all help / error messages
```

Comment: First you should take this opportunity to learn about `MPI_Bcast()` and `MPI_Reduce()`. Compile with `-Wall` and fix the all the warnings related to use of uninitialized variables. Then unless you moved to broadcast/reduce, fix the next issue that will occur in `MPI_Send()`.

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet But the program is working if I remove the MPI_Wtime() and all other variables related to it, I just want to calculate the time to run this program

Comment: You should focus on fixing the undefined behavior(s) on your program instead of looking for workarounds.

Comment: _"But the program is working if I remove..."_.  If you have undefined behavior lurking, it may appear that your program is working solidly, but it is actually running as a time bomb...  Suggest you follow suggestions to address UB before trusting appearances that program is working.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your behaviour where removing the Wtime call "fixes" the program, but I suspect what is happening is this:

Your variable "source" is not set. Unset variables have some garbage-value, but they can often be zero. See this question [What does uninitialised memory contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73473591/what-does-uninitialised-memory-contain)

If your uninitialized source is 0, than it actually has the correct value for the first set of recv-calls. If it is not zero, there is probably no rank with that number, and the call fails.

Answering why the Wtime-call may or may not make it so that on your specific system (compiler+os+hardware+libraries etc) the uninitialized value happens to be zero is hard and also a bit useless. A C-Program that reads an uninitialized variable has so-called "Undefined Behaviour" and can do anything. It is important to understand the concept of undefined behaviour when programming in C. The c-faq describes it like this:

> **undefined:** Anything at all can happen; the Standard imposes no requirements. The program may fail to compile, or it may execute incorrectly (either crashing or silently generating incorrect results), or it may fortuitously do exactly what the programmer intended.

(https://c-faq.com/ansi/undef.html)

This makes C really quite different from most programming languages in terms of debugging and it is the reason commenters advice you to enable compiler-warnings and fix them.